# How to get id of the selected item in combobox and populate another combobox with it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, combobox, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have 2 comboboxes created with `Ajax Toolkit`. One of them has a list of systems. I wanted to fill the other combobox with a list of subsystems whenever a system is selected. I did not use `DisplayMember` or `ValueMember` and most examples are using them.
.aspx side just in case:

```
<ajaxToolkit:ComboBox ID="cbox1" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="cbox1_SelectedIndexChanged" />
```

Is this doable with what I'm trying? Is the event I used correct for the situation?(I guess not,but other events seem to be unrelated) Let me show you the code:

```
protected void fillSystemCombo()
        {
            var sysOperations = new ModelOperations.ConstantSystem.ConstantSystemOperations();
            var sys = sysOperations.GetSystemList().TransactionResultList;

            foreach (var item in sys)
            {
                cbox1.Items.Add(item.description);
            }
        }
```

This works fine and I can see the systems in my first combobox.

This is what I tried for populating the second one:

```
protected void cbox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var subSysOperations = new ModelOperations.ConstantSubSystem.ConstantSubSystemOperations();
            int index = Convert.ToInt32(cbox1.SelectedItem.Value);//i think this should get the id...

            var subsys = subSysOperations.GetSubSystemList().TransactionResultList;

            foreach (var item in subsys)
            {
                if (item.sysID == index)
                {
                    cbox2.Items.Add(item.description);
                }
            }
        }
```

`sysID` is the foreign key in SubSystem which is the `ID` of System. By the way, my `SelectedIndexChanged` event never fired when I was debugging the program even though I clicked on an item in combobox.

Comment: Why are you not setting the source of the combo box, with the display and value members?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've actually found the answer after carefully reading the parameters taken by `Items.Add`. It wants a `ListItem`so if I create a `ListItem` inside the loop I can finally add my items with both a `Text` and a `Value` like this:

```
   foreach (var item in sys)
            {
                combo1.Items.Add(new ListItem { Text = item.description, Value = item.ID.ToString() });
            }
```

After that I can get the index with

```
int index = Convert.ToInt32(combo1.SelectedValue);
```